# clear command in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

When I type `clear` in MySql and execute it, `exit` MySql console and try to login again, it doesn't take the password I used to log in. I have to reconfigure the MySql server. 
Can anyone explain why is this happening?

Comment: `Clear` shouldn't have any effect on password settings. If you *don't* use `clear`, exit the console and try to login again, does it take the password? What do you do to "reconfigure" your server? In my mind, the following situation could have happened: you try to reset the password, but it doesn't actually work. You think that the fact it doesn't work has to do with `clear`. (So try the same without `clear`). To eliminate the "in my mind"-thingy, you should elaborate a bit more about what you tried exactly, and what happens.

Answer (score 0):

The `clear` command just **clears** the current input statement, and it doesn't have any effect on the user configuration like passwords

So in order to clear reset configuration try using `exit` to **log out**

Hope helpfull.